# header content-type changes between curl_multi_add_handle and curl_multi_perform

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I have created a cURL post with headers in a c++ application:

```
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());               
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &bufferdata);     
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writerResponse);

struct curl_slist *headers=NULL;
char outputmessage[]="";            

headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: application/json");
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers );
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, cJSONstring.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, cJSONstring.length());
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,1);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER,1);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION, my_trace);

curl_multi_add_handle(m_telemetryCurlm, curl);
```

I have created a thread to call multi perform:

```
void ContentManager::processTelemetry()
{
    m_telemetryThreadRunning = true;
    while(m_telemetryThreadRunning)
    {
        static_cast<ADCAnalytics*>(m_adcAnalytics)->performTelemerty();
        usleep(5000); 
    }   
}

void ADCAnalytics::performTelemerty()
{   
    // number of active downloads
    int counter = 0;

    // preform downloading
    curl_multi_perform(m_telemetryCurlm, &counter);     

    // handle CURL actions (connection errors, download finish, etc.)
    checkCURLMessages();    
}
```

but when I check the curl messages I get:

12-10 13:23:00.845: I/ADC(17248): buffer = HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

12-10 13:23:00.845: I/ADC(17248): X-TraceUrl: /appstats/details?time=1355145806563&type=json

12-10 13:23:00.845: I/ADC(17248): Content-Type: text/plain

12-10 13:23:00.845: I/ADC(17248): Vary: Accept-Encoding

12-10 13:23:00.845: I/ADC(17248): Date: Mon, 10 Dec 2012 13:23:26 GMT

12-10 13:23:00.845: I/ADC(17248): Server: Google Frontend

12-10 13:23:00.845: I/ADC(17248): Cache-Control: private

12-10 13:23:00.845: I/ADC(17248): Transfer-Encoding: chunked

It seems that the content-type is changed between curl_multi_add_handle and curl_multi_perform. Does anybody has any idea what is wrong here? What can I do to avoid content-type to change?

When adding the following code

```
         do {
        while(curl_multi_perform(m_telemetryCurlm, &still_running) ==CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);                                 
    } while (still_running);
```

immediately after setting the cURL object. The request is sent to the server and  I get

12-10 13:11:48.105: I/ADC(16845): buffer = HTTP/1.1 200 OK

12-10 13:11:48.105: I/ADC(16845): X-TraceUrl: /appstats/details?time=1355145133776&type=json

12-10 13:11:48.105: I/ADC(16845): Content-Type: application/json

12-10 13:11:48.105: I/ADC(16845): Vary: Accept-Encoding

12-10 13:11:48.105: I/ADC(16845): Date: Mon, 10 Dec 2012 13:12:13 GMT

12-10 13:11:48.105: I/ADC(16845): Server: Google Frontend

12-10 13:11:48.105: I/ADC(16845): Cache-Control: private

12-10 13:11:48.105: I/ADC(16845): Transfer-Encoding: chunked
So, I don't believe is something wrong on the server side.

Thanks

Comment: POST on your server and see the request details. Maybe the problem is on their side

Comment: Sorry for the previous message, I have edited my question why I don't think the problem is on server side.

Comment: Why don't you check it? It's not hard to make a script of 5 lines or ness and post on it to be sure. Maybe that three minutes of your time will solve the whole issue

Comment: I have check with postman in Chrome and the request works from there.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you comparing the Content-Type you SEND with the one you RECEIVE?

Comment: In my example both content type for SEND and RECEIVE are application/json. But for some reason the SEND content type is changing to text/plain.

Comment: "HTTP/1.1 400" and "HTTP/1.1 200" imply that they are response headers